# Is SSR enabled while using Client-Components in Next.JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I was trying out the new features from Next.js 13 and I can't explain to myself, why Client Components still use SSR. I thought that using Client Components would result in Components that are only rendered on the client.

Can anyone explain, how that exactly works?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Server-side rendering basically means fetching the data on the server. So when the server sends the html to the browser, it already populates the HTML, so the search crawler will see HTML with populated data so your page will be indexed higher. Once the HTML is sent down to the browser, the browser will parse the HTML and your page will have javascript interactivity, `onClick`, `mouseOver` etc. All the client components in next.js uses ssr.

However, the server component is a different concept. Entire HTML is rendered on the server so any dependency used on the server will stay on the server. So your browser will receive the HTML with data in JSON format, build it but it will not go through all javascript. so client bundle size will decrease and your app performance will increase.